How can I get my Conan recipe to require a certain version of CMake?
I'm updating a Conan recipe of a library of mine. This library now requires a relatively new version of CMake to run. How do I "tell" Conan - or at least, the PR action checkers on github.com for the Conan package index - that CMake version XYZ or later is required?

You could use version ranges: self.tool_requires("cmake/[>3.15]"). For full reference see:
https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/intro_to_versioning.html#version-ranges

In case you don't want to touch your recipe, by adding CMake as tool requirement, you still can install cmake from your profile by using tool_requires directly in your Conan profile file: https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/config_files/profiles.html

@uilianries: I actually do want to touch the recipe, so your first recommendation should be appropriate. Writing that up as an answer.

@uilianries: Ok, so - that didn't work... No effect on the GitHub runner, it still used CMake 3.15.x

You probably are missing --update when running conan install or conan create. Conan client, by default, will look into your Conan cache first, and if it finds an expected version that matches the required range, it will use your cache instead. If you need a newer version available in your Conan remote, you first need to say to Conan, by passing the parameter --update so it will look for a newer version available in your remote.

@uilianries: But I dont say anything to conan... it's all the runner's job. The only thing I can do is edit the recipe (or the pull request page on github.com)

in your PR, you are using requirements but it should be build_requirements instead. Please, read https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/conanfile/methods/build_requirements.html
